Doing variation with VarD or VarAction in xAct
I am doing some calculation about the variation of Einstein-Hilbert action considering metric perturbation $h_{\mu\nu}$ (with $g_{\mu\nu}=\bar{g}_{\mu\nu}+\epsilon h_{\mu\nu}$), the variation quite confuses me
for example, if doing the perturbation of the Ricci curvature $R$, we would get some terms like $\bar{g}^{\beta\delta}(\bar{\nabla}_{\alpha}C^{\alpha}_{\;\beta\delta}-\bar{\nabla}_{\delta}C^{\alpha}_{\;\beta\alpha})$, where $C^{\alpha}_{\;\beta\delta}=\frac{1}{2}\bar{g}^{\alpha\lambda}(\bar{\nabla}_{\beta}h_{\lambda\delta}+\bar{\nabla}_{\delta}h_{\lambda\beta}-\bar{\nabla}_{\lambda}h_{\beta\delta})$.
here we consider the $h_{\mu\nu}$ is a tensor field independent of the metric(even it is not symmetric).
I want to calculate the variation of $\bar{g}^{\beta\delta}(\bar{\nabla}_{\alpha}C^{\alpha}_{\;\beta\delta})$ with respect to metric tensor $g$, how to do it with VarD in xAct?
In my point of view, the result should be

however, using VarD
<< xAct`xPert`;
$PrePrint = ScreenDollarIndices;
$CovDFormat = "Prefix";
$DefInfoQ = False;
DefManifold[M4, 
  4, {\[Alpha], \[Beta], \[Gamma], \[Mu], \[Nu], \[Rho], \[Sigma], \
\[Kappa]}];
DefMetric[-1, Met[-\[Mu], -\[Nu]], 
  CD, {";", "\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(\[Del]\), \(_\)]\)"}, 
  PrintAs -> "\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(g\), \(_\)]\)"];
DefMetricPerturbation[Met, \[Delta]Met, \[Tau], PrintAs -> "h"];
DefTensor[h1[-\[Alpha], -\[Beta]], M4] ;
PrintAs[RiemannCD] ^= "R";
PrintAs[RicciCD] ^= "R";
PrintAs[RicciScalarCD] ^= "R";
PrintAs[DetMet] ^= "\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(g\), \(_\)]\)"

and
DefTensor[C1[\[Alpha], \[Beta], \[Gamma]], M4];
C1[\[Mu]_, \[Beta]_, \[Delta]_] := 
 1/2*(CD[\[Beta]][h1[\[Mu], \[Delta]]] + 
    CD[\[Delta]][h1[\[Mu], \[Beta]]] - 
    CD[\[Mu]][h1[\[Beta], \[Delta]]])
expr = Sqrt[-DetMet[]] CD[-\[Alpha]][
    C1[\[Alpha], -\[Beta], -\[Delta]]]*Met[\[Beta], \[Delta]];
expr = % // SeparateMetric[];
VarD[Met[-\[Mu], -\[Nu]], CD]@expr;
% // Simplification

or
DefTensor[C2[\[Alpha], \[Beta], \[Gamma]], M4];
C2[\[Mu]_, \[Beta]_, \[Delta]_] := 
 1/2*(CD[\[Beta]][\[Delta]Met[LI[1], \[Mu], \[Delta]]] + 
    CD[\[Delta]][\[Delta]Met[LI[1], \[Mu], \[Beta]]] - 
    CD[\[Mu]][\[Delta]Met[LI[1], \[Beta], \[Delta]]])
expr2 = Sqrt[-DetMet[]] CD[-\[Alpha]][
    C2[\[Alpha], -\[Beta], -\[Delta]]]*Met[\[Beta], \[Delta]];
expr2 = % // SeparateMetric[];
VarD[Met[-\[Mu], -\[Nu]], CD]@expr2;
% // Simplification

obtain

which has a discrepency with the hand calculation, also
I found the example "ActionVariation_Metric_Fields.nb" of C.Pitrou (link),
using VarAction(varies with respect to Lagrangian density, in default neglecting $\sqrt{-g}$),
expr2 = CD[-\[Alpha]][C1[\[Alpha], -\[Beta], -\[Delta]]]*
   Met[\[Beta], \[Delta]];
VarAction[expr2, Met[-\[Mu], -\[Nu]]]; 
result = % // Simplify

get

is also different
